# Is it possible to use 1 html file to view different items on different pages?

Tags: html

I am currently in the process of creating a website for a small enterprise. I made a nav item called "Collections" where it is divided into various categories for the type of products that will be sold (Rings, Bracelets etc). And then Under "Rings" (when selected), multiple items that can be bought are displayed in a gallery form (image + a "click here for more details"just below). When you select an individual item, a new page (target="_blank") will open that will display price/description of said selected item.

Since in the future, there will probably be hundreds of items with their price/descriptions, should i make an individual html file for each? Or is there a way to have 1 html file and a new page opening depending on which item was selected?

Comment: Aren't you trying to create a dynamic site? If you use a server side scripting language like php or whatever, you need to create only one html-like model of your desired product details page, the server side script will handle everything else according to user's request and fetch everything needed from database. 

And if you are thinking that you will create each product's page individually, then that is unusual, time consuming and not really used anywhere for business purpose.

Comment: Since you want to build an e-commerce site, you would need a back-end language to achieve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for single page application, since you are building an e-commerce website there would be click events to show product description.creating individual page for each product is time consuming.From your question i believe you want load the product details on the same page which can be achieved by loading data from your back end and implementing a templating system in the front end.
have a look at

https://angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking at creating an e-commerce site and needing help on the simpler bits then I would suggest that you look into using a dedicated hosted e-commerce platform such as Shopify, Squarespace or if you want to self host Magento or Prestashop.

This is because once money is involved, rolling your own platform when you're not an expert isn't a great idea.

There's a post here: https://www.upwork.com/hiring/for-clients/self-hosted-vs-hosted-e-commerce-platforms-right/ which could help you decide what is best for you.

Comment: I should not have used the word e-commerce, my bad. Payment through the website itself will not be available.

Comment: I don't think it's a link-only answer. Although providing with a relevant piece of information, it should be deleted because it simply does not answers the OP's question (*should i make an individual html file for each?*)